# OpenCV library for tennis ball detection using Hough Circle Transformation

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I am using opencv library for tennis ball detection for my project in real time. I am using Hough circle transform method for detection, what it does is find a number of circles in the image including object. So it is hard to get the correct coordinate of center and radius of the required object from the image

So anybody have any idea to solve this problem..........?

Comment: Use color to choose valid object.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas here for you:

The more general approach would be to filter your found circles by size, circularity, or some other property you could think of. This way, you only find the circles you really care about. This takes the least amount of knowledge of the specific object you are looking for.

The more specific approach is to assume that you are looking only for a tennis ball (is this right?). Since that's what you're looking for, you can pre-process the images (threshold, morph filter, etc.) before running the hough algorithm, to get rid of some of the noise. For example, let's say you have a plain old, neon green tennis ball, and that's all you care about:

Step 1: Transform image to HSV space (not necessary, but I prefer it that way)

Step 2: Split the channels

Step 3: Threshold each channel, looking for a specific value of Hue, Saturation and Value that correspond to your particular tennis ball. You will likely have to experiment with these numeric values to see which give you the best picture of the ball.

Step 4: bitwise_and the results of the channel thresholds together, to create one final binarized image of (hopefully, by now) just the tennis ball

Step 5: Hough circle algorithm, and proceed as usual.

I hope this sheds some light on your situation. -JB

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I would like to go with your advice but i have not much idea on HSV image. It will be so nice of you if you give me detail or any reference related to HSV image...